Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in FBReactNativeSpec on Xcode 15.4
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run/build my React Native project in Xcode 15.4. The error occurs in the FBReactNativeSpec and the build fails with the following message:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Details:
React Native Version: 0.71.8
Xcode Version: 15.4
macOS Version: macOS 14.5
What I've Tried:

Cleaning the build folder: Product > Clean Build Folder
Reinstalling npm packages: Deleted node_modules and ran npm install (or yarn
install)
Reinstalling pods: Deleted Pods folder and Podfile.lock and ran pod install in the ios directory
Clearing Derived Data: Deleted contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Updating React Native and related packages: Ensured all dependencies are up-to-date
Despite these efforts, the error persists.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it?

When I cloned my repository, I renamed it from "WalletClone" to "WalletClone Copy", introducing a space. This caused the above error.
Solution

To fix this issue, I renamed the repository to
"WalletClone_Copy", ensuring there are no spaces in the
name.
Then clean and build

